# Capture number inside square brackets after # sign

Tags: php, regex

I have email subjects that contain this part:

```
[Message #15]
```

I want to extract the number 15 from the subject, how would I achieve it? Using PHP preferably but any regex answer is acceptable.

Comment: you need to provide the regex that you have attempted, we will then help you from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
'/\[[^#\]]*#(\d+)(?=\])/'
```

And use captured group #1.

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/cZ1pO7)

Comment: Otherwise `/\[[^#]+#([^\]]+)\]/Uis`

Comment: @ridgerunner: Thanks, That is really good point, I edited it.

Comment: @AmalMurali: Thanks my friend for updating demo link also.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown any other possibilities, but this will do it without regex:

```
strtok($string, '#');
$number = strtok(']');
```

Answer (score 0):

Print out only the number:

```
 $text    = '[Message #15]';
 $number  = preg_replace("/\[[^#]+#([^\]]+)\]/Uis", "$1", $text);
 print $number;
```

Comment: The `U` modifier is _never a good idea_ (it is _never_ needed and only serves to confuse). And in this particular case, you don't want or need the quantifier to be lazy anyhow. Also the first char class needs to exclude the right square bracket too. As-is the pattern; `/\[[^#]+#([^\]]+)\]/` erroneously matches the non-message in the string: `"out1 [not a message] out2 [Message #15] out3"`